# Update branch name pattern

Tags: github

Can we update the GitHub branch protection rules with branch-name-pattern using REST API? I am currently doing a PUT request:

```bash
PUT /repos/{owner}/{repo}/branches/protection/branch-name-pattern

    {
      "branch_name_pattern": "{new_branch_name_pattern}"
    }
```

This is giving me a error 422. Are there any other methods to try this?

Comment: What's the actual value you're trying to send?

Answer (score 0):

> branch protection rules with branch-name-pattern using REST API

This feature is gone (you'll get a 410 with a GET). You can only manage the protection of specific branches through the REST API. The feature you are looking for has been transferred to the GraphQL API.

> `https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/branches/BRANCH/protection`
>
> [...]
>
> ###### `branch` string Required
>
> The name of the branch. **Cannot contain wildcard characters**. To use wildcard characters in branch names, use the GraphQL API.

Refer to the latest documentation on branch protection:

- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/branches/branch-protection?apiVersion=2022-11-28#update-branch-protection

And here you can find the documention for the GraphQL API:

- https://docs.github.com/fr/graphql